# Polymer image layout

Tags: polymer

I am a newbie at polymer. I wanted to create a simple custom element whereby I have a total of 4 images displayed on an image grid of 2 columns and 2 rows. I would like to use flexbox. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Hikma

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not about Polymer, it's about flexbox.

Here's one way to do it:

```
display : flex;
flex-wrap : wrap;
```

See this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPdPdV

And here's a great reference to flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

It would be helpful to other users if you updated your question's title and tags to correspond to the question's content.